# $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$ converges?

Tags: integration

If $f(x), g(x) > 0$ on $(0, \infty)$, and $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges, and $lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=L$, $L > 0$, then is $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$ converges? For this one I can't think of a counterexample, because if I make $g(x)=e^{-x}+1$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and they still converges.

Comment: **Hint :** You cannot find a counterexample because it is true.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thank you, but how do you know it's true

Comment: There exists $A$ such that for $x \geq A$, you have $g(x) \leq L+1$. So for $x \geq A$, $f(x)g(x) \leq f(x)(L+1)$ so by comparison the integral converges.

Comment: The problem isn’t near infinity. but the integral can fail near $1.$ For example, if both $f$ and $g$ are approximately $\frac1{\sqrt{|x-1|}}$ near $1,$ then $\int_1^2 f(x)g(x)\,dx$ doesn’t converge. But if $f,g$ are continuous on $[1,\infty]$ then this theorem is true. More particularly, it is true if $g$ is bounded, even if not continuous.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why is the point $x=1$ special?  Your argument would apply for any $x\ge 1$.

Comment: @MarkViola whoops, yes, you are correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews And I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy.